# Unable to access remotely via RDP while logged into the Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: 22.04, remote-desktop, rdp

I am trying to access my Ubuntu 22.04 machine remotely from a windows machine by using RDP. If I am logged into the Ubuntu machine then the access does not work and I only see a black screen. On the other hand, if I am logged out of the Ubuntu machine then I can access the machine using RDP. Even though, the screen I access works a bit differently than the normal Ubuntu screen. For example, no icons or sidebars (with program icons) appear on the desktop and there is no option to minimize any window, either we change or close the window.
Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not see the same Desktop interface because you need to perform some additional post configuration actions.

To get the same desktop interface with the docker; you will need to execute the following command in a terminal  console

```
sudo sed -i "4 a #Improved Look n Feel Method\ncat <<EOF > ~/.xsessionrc\nexport GNOME_SHELL_SESSION_MODE=ubuntu\nexport XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=ubuntu:GNOME\nexport XDG_CONFIG_DIRS=/etc/xdg/xdg-ubuntu:/etc/xdg\nEOF\n" /etc/xrdp/startwm.sh
```

This code will update the file /etc/xrdp/startwm.sh and will tell the system that each time you login via xRDP, a file called .xsession will be created.   The .xession file will import necessary environment variable needed to run your desktop properly. The code above is only valid if you are running Gnome Desktop interface !!!

If you want to visit our blog, we have developed a small script that can help easy installation of xRDP.. . if you want to give it a try and read more about it, please check [this link](https://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=18725)

Hope this help
Till next time
See ya

Answer (score 0):

Black Screen situation Explained

"As mentioned and explained multiple times,  this situation will happen (or can happen) when the same user account is used concurrently locally and remotely.  In other words,  the problem is related to the fact that the same user account is already logged in locally and a remote connection is attempted at the same time.  With xRDP software solution, a specific user account can be logged on either locally or remotely but not both..."

Answering to your first question please read more about it here : https://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=16682

Giving patch to your second issue is like

1.) Right click with your mouse on the address bar of your Ubuntu window and choose the "minimize" option.
2.) It minimizes your Ubuntu window

If you would like to understand more about xrdp that is running on your Ubuntu please read this : https://github.com/neutrinolabs/xrdp/wiki

Comment: Thank you for explaining. One question, why I can not see the programs dock in the remote session?

Comment: I guess because of gnome desktop. I read about it somewhere that different workspaces work differently with xrdp. I installed the `gnome-tweaks` package but I haven't found option regarding to the dock visibility. Summing up I don't know why it is not visible.